# Кнопка QPushButton

Tags: c++, qt5

Есть класс с унаследованной кнопой:

```
EnterButton::EnterButton(QPushButton *parent) : QPushButton(parent)
{
    QPixmap                 pixButton(":/img/Images/button.png");
    setIcon(pixButton);
    setIconSize(pixButton.size());
}
```

который работает (не так как хотелось бы), а именно:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

по бокам рамка, как от нее избавиться что б было читое изображение?

Comment: Я бы сделал кликабельный qlabel -- тоже наследование, но с переопределением mouseReleaseEvent и отправки своего сигнала clicked. А ваш вариант я бы попробовал через qstylesheet -- убрать рамку проблем не вызовет

Comment: а установить размеры кнопки относительно размеров картинки? Типа `QPushButton alfa; alfa.setSize(pixButton.size());` - вроде так, если не ошибся

Comment: Я бы тоже делал через stylesheet. Как минимум, в вашем случае нажатие на кнопку будет срабатывать когда мышь не на кнопке, не очень хорошее пользовательское взаимодействие.

Comment: Я особо не пользуюсь QT, но по логике  вам нужно сделать  QPushButton *parent  нулевым по умолчанию или  наследование сделать закрытым или защищенным

Comment: `QPushButton::setFlat(true)` подойдет?

Comment: @acade Рамки нет, в принципе желаемый результат по данному вопросу, единственно то что не так это эффект при нажатии, но это уже другая история) буду разбираться.

Comment: @acade Напишите свой ответ, что б я мог галочку поставить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Класс `QPushButton` содержит свойство `flat`, которое определяет наличие границ у кнопки.
`bool isFlat() const` - возвращает `true`, если свойство `flat` установлено и `false` в противном случае.

`void setFlat(bool)` - устанавливает значение свойства `flat`.

Некоторые ссылки для получения информации по Qt:

[Qt Wiki ru](https://wiki.qt.io/Main/ru) - wiki гайд на русском

[Qt Documentation Archives](http://doc.qt.io/archives/index.html) - архив документации qt (на английском)